# Windows Courier Font Looks Extremely "Thin"

Tags: windows, html, css

I'm currently working on a web-application which I would like to have using Courier.
Things work almost all fine apart from the fact that Courier is displated extremely thin on browsers running on Windows.
I know that OSX by-nature renders displays fonts on the "bolder" side however the situation with Windows seems horrific.

My questions:

- How can I increase font-weight on Windows? I do not seek to get font-weight: bold; because that's too much.
- Which other font should I use instead of Courier to increase readability on Windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are the options for font-weight. But be aware that most often there are only a few weights available for a particular font family. When a specific weight is set, and no face exists, a face with a nearby weight is used ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/)). So even if you set the weight at `500`, which should be slightly thicker than the normal, it may still look the same.

If your concern is "readability" then you should consider using a different font. The general consensus is that sans-serif fonts are more "readable" on screens than serif fonts, so instead you should use something like `Helvetica` or `Verdana`... (`font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;`)

Font-Weights:

`100` - Thin

`200` - Extra Light (Ultra Light)

`300` - Light

`400` - Normal

`500` - Medium

`600` - Semi Bold (Demi Bold)

`700` - Bold

`800` - Extra Bold (Ultra Bold)

`900` - Black (Heavy)

`normal` - Same as ‘400’.

`bold` - Same as ‘700’.

`bolder` - Specifies the weight of the face bolder than the inherited value.

`lighter` - Specifies the weight of the face lighter than the inherited value.

BTW `Courier` and `Courier New` look fine on my Windows browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Modern versions of Windows do not have Courier. Old versions had such a font, typically a bitmap font of poor quality. Modern versions map the font name Courier to Courier New, a much better font. It may look somewhat thin, though.

Courier New has only two font weights, normal and bold. If neither of them suits your preferences, consider using a different font. (Artificial bolding-like modification is possible in a sense using `text-shadow`, but even a shadow of one pixel produces an appearance that looks bolder than the bold typeface.)

If you need a monospace font, instead of Courier or Courier New, consider using Lucida Console (available in most Windows systems) or Consolas (available in modern Windows system). They have stronger stroke width.